# Changing object values only when save() method is called

Tags: java

I need help passing a test, but can't seem to find the solution anywhere. I have a code for determining the bonus points for customers. I get my info from a text file and I need to give customers bonus points based on vairables. The catch is that the bonus points should only be added when used the save() method, which overwrites the text file. I have a CustomerRepository class:

```
public class CustomerRepository {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "src/poly/customer/data.txt";
    public List<AbstractCustomer> customers;

    public CustomerRepository() {
        try {
            this.customers = readFiles();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public List<AbstractCustomer> readFiles() throws IOException{
        List<AbstractCustomer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Path.of(FILE_PATH));
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] parts = line.split(";");
            int points = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
            if (parts[0].equals("REGULAR")) {
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(parts[4], formatter);
                RegularCustomer customer = new RegularCustomer(parts[1], parts[2], points, date);
                result.add(customer);
            } else if (parts[0].equals("GOLD")) {
                GoldCustomer customer = new GoldCustomer(parts[1], parts[2], points);
                result.add(customer);
            } else {
                throw new IOException();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

public void save(AbstractCustomer customer) {
        if (!(customers.contains(customer))) {
            customers.add(customer);
        }
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (AbstractCustomer client : customers) {
            result.append(client.toString());
            result.append("\n");
        }
        try{
            File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(result.toString());
            bw.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This class is working, but I don't know how to give customer objects points only when they are saved. I also have RegularCustomer and GoldCustomer classes which extend the AbstractCustomer class:

```
public abstract sealed class AbstractCustomer permits GoldCustomer, RegularCustomer {

    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected int bonusPoints;

    public AbstractCustomer(String id, String name, int bonusPoints) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.bonusPoints = bonusPoints;
    }

    public abstract void collectBonusPointsFrom(Order order);

public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getBonusPoints() {
        return bonusPoints;
    }
```

The code itself is working fine and does the intended things, but my only problem is passing this test:

```
@Test
    public void customerIsChangedOnlyWhenSaved() {
        String randomId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        repository.save(new RegularCustomer(
                randomId, "David", 0, LocalDate.now()));

        AbstractCustomer customer = repository.getCustomerById(randomId).get();

        assertThat(customer.getBonusPoints(), is(0));

        customer.collectBonusPointsFrom(new Order(200, LocalDate.now()));

        assertThat(customer.getBonusPoints(), is(not(0)));

        AbstractCustomer loaded = repository.getCustomerById(randomId).get();

        assertThat(loaded.getBonusPoints(), is(0));
    }
```

This test creates a new customer and adds a order, but the customer bonuspoints should not change, because it is not saved. My code still adds the points and overwrites the file.

There is also a BonusCollector class, which collects bonus points from order, but this class shouldn't be modified.

This is the implementation for collectBonusPoints(Order order):

```
@Override
    public void collectBonusPointsFrom(Order order) {
        if (order.getTotal() >= 100) {
            double points = order.getTotal();
            if (isWithinAMonth(order.getDate())) {
                this.bonusPoints += Math.toIntExact(Math.round(points * 1.5));
                this.lastOrderDate = order.getDate();
            } else {
                this.bonusPoints += Math.toIntExact(Math.round(points));
                this.lastOrderDate = order.getDate();
            }
        }
    }
```

The gold customer implementation is a bit different.

Comment: What's the content of the file after this test? There's a call to save() in your test.

Comment: Unrelated: research "java try with resources". Your code is wrong on some subtle details. And note: throwing an IOException without any message when the "type" of customer is unknown is a bad idea. When your code throws an exception, then make it meaningful by picking a good class (it is not an IO error when your file contains unexpected content), and then: give a meaningful, human comprehensible error message.

Comment: Can you give the implementation of collectBonusPointsFrom(Order order)?

Comment: @Maritim REGULAR;e8e8e85d-44a7-4410-bc7c-6c19e14bc86c;David;0;2022-05-01. This is correct, but the customer object still has 200 points, but should have 0 because the change was not saved

Comment: @mariqvlahova I added it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with persisting state.In abstractcustomer class you need to have get method and from this method to return the clone of the object to be able to pass the test.

```
public class Customer {
protected String id;
protected String name;
protected int bonusPoints;
public Customer(String id, String name, int bonusPoints) {
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.bonusPoints = bonusPoints;
}
public void collectBonusPointsFrom(Order order) {
 ....
}
public String getId() {
return id;
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public Integer getBonusPoints() {
return bonusPoints;
}
public Customer get(){
//if you don`t return new object  you will work directly with the one from repo
return new Customer(id,name,bonusPoints);
}
}
```

The full code you can find -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FOeF68RO-qI4CO9mJ92rKlQ8MNigWbof/view?usp=sharing